# How to group my subreports into 1 header & 2 details output

Tags: reporting-services

Currently I've created below report with total of 3 subreports, the expectation was using DN_Header as main header sub report for PickSlip header & PickSlip details.

But it seems the output I'm having now is totally a mess whereby "DN_HEader" only show 1 of the data & applied toward all sub reports which is not right.
[image: Wrong output]

So how can i make it into such output? I'm not familiar with the grouping if there's any good reference that will be great. Thanks
[image: Expected output]

Comment: Google is your friend ;-) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/lesson-6-adding-grouping-and-totals-reporting-services and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/subreports-report-builder-and-ssrs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a few sub reports. You may have most of them completed already but I'll go thru them.

Here's a rough sketch of the layout based on your expected output image.

[image]

NOTE: Subreports A and B could be combined into a single report. It depends if you plan to use any parts elsewhere. Combining then might make this a little easier.

1. Subreport A. This is just you details section. It should accept parameters to filter data as applicable.
2. Subreport B. This will be your details header plus your details body. Again it must accept parameters to filter data as applicable.
3. SubReport C. This will contain a header and a single cell tablix. This will contains a dataset that returns 1 record for every instance of subreport B that needs to be shown. It will contain a tablix with a single cell. The tablix's dataset will point to the new dataset. In the cell, insert a subreport and set it to point to SubReportB. Finally pass in parameters from the dataset tho the subreport (in the subreport properties) so SubReportB shows the correct data.
4. Main report. This will be very similar to subreportC, it will contains a single cell tablix containing SubReport C in it's cell and dataset that will be used to loop thru each required instance of SubReport C

Hope that makes sense?

Comment: This is exactly what i need & now I'm able to generate the output as expected result & also I've put some page-break on individual grouping.